# Why does accessing integer variables using character pointers in C causes truncation to one byte only?

Tags: c, pointers

For the following piece of C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a=317;
char *ptr;
int *ptrr;

ptr=(char *)&a;
printf("%d\n",*ptr);
return(0);
}
```

The output is:

```
61
```

The binary of 317 is 00000001 00111101

And that for 61 is   00000000 00111101

It seems like the the pointer in this code is accessing only one byte instead of two.But,if I am not wrong,sizes of both char and int pointers are the same.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because a char is one byte and an int is no less than two bytes.

Comment: Size of pointer is unimportant, size of pointee is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Size of a `char` and `int` pointer might be same, but size of `char` and `int` are not same!! So, when you use a pointer to character type to access any other object type, it points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Next, when you dereference it, all you got the value of that *byte*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> [...] When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
>   the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the
>   result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

That said, to add more context, regarding *Address and indirection operators* §6.5.3.2

> The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
>   a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the
>   object. [....]

and, for an "object" of type `char`, from chapter §6.5.3.4

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. [....]

and

> When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or
>   `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1. [...]

So, the size of a `char` type is defined to be 1 (1 byte) in C, and hence, the dereference takes place accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer basically "points" to a memory address, and the type of the pointer (e.g. `char*` or `int*`) defines how to interpret the content at this memory address. So the size of the pointer itself is the same, regardless of whether it points to an integer or to a character. But when accessing the content to which the pointer points to (i.e. when dereferencing the pointer), the respective value is read according to the type of the pointer (i.e. one byte for `char`, and probably 4 bytes for `int`).

`ptr` will point to the begin of the memory where your object represented by `a` is stored. Whether the result in your case is `61` or `0` depends on whether your system has a big endian or a little endian architecture.